# Python3 app calling Python2 script through subprocess make the logging module buggy

Tags: python, logging

This is a strange question...

I am developping a Python3 base application (MY_APP) that needs to call at some point another Python application (REQ_APP).

MY_APP can use any Python3 version although REQ_APP can only use either Python2.7 or Python3.4. That's because it loads so libraries linked with Python2.7 or Python3.4 development libraries.

I don't want to have this app only available through virtual environment so I don't see another option than calling REQ_APP with my installed Python2.7 through a subprocess call withing MY_APP.

Knowing that, MY_APP is using the logging module, and REQ_APP as well with a different config and that leads to some strange logging messages like:

`[MODCON]  2019-10-04 09:59:39     DEBUG  format '{date} {time} - {id} - {maintype} - {msg}' -> '(?P<date>.+?) (?P<time>.+?) - (?P<id>.+?) - (?P<maintype>.+?) - (?P<msg>.+?)'`

This is a logging call from REQ_APP. It defines it's own logging though but it uses my configuration I defined in MY_APP. Is there a way to avoid this logging conflict? Can I do conditional configuration of the logging module depending on the caller file? Note that since REQ_APP is not mine, I cannot modify the source code, even if I can see it!